# php - if statement in a while loop

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having problems getting my simple if-statement to work inside a PHP while loop. This is my code:

```
$p=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE forum_id='$cid' AND topic_id='$id' AND post_deleted='0' ORDER BY post_time ASC LIMIT  $offset, $rowsperpage");

while($post=mysql_fetch_assoc($p)){ 
    $userpost=$user->getUserData($post['userid']);

          if($userpost['specialmembership'] == 1){
            $pioneer = "True";
          }
echo $userpost['username'];
echo $pioneer;

}
```

So, in the above example I have two different users. They are named `user1` and `user2`.

- User1 has specialmembership = 0
- User2 has specialmembership = 1

The above code will output the following (the while loop in this example is getting looped **4 times**):

It will output:

```
user1

user2
true

user1
true

user2
true
```

The problem is here, that the script is printing out true on user1 in the third loop. User1 shouldn't be set to true, only user2 should that, since he has `specialmembership = 1;`

What is wrong here?

Comment: Reset the value of `$pioneer` to false as the first line inside your while loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add an `else`

```
if($userpost['specialmembership'] == 1){
      $pioneer = "True";
}else {
     $pioneer = "False";
}
```

Because once the value of `$pioneer` is set does not change (if you don't do it again)

Answer (score 3):

You never reset `$pioneer` after it's set to true, so ALL users after the first 'true' user will also be true. You need an else:

```
      if($userpost['specialmembership'] == 1){
        $pioneer = "True";
      } else {
        $pioneer = "False";  // <---you need this
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following

```
$p=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE forum_id='$cid' AND topic_id='$id' AND post_deleted='0' ORDER BY post_time ASC LIMIT  $offset, $rowsperpage");

while($post=mysql_fetch_assoc($p)){ 
    $userpost=$user->getUserData($post['userid']);

            $pioneer = "False";
          if($userpost['specialmembership'] == 1){
            $pioneer = "True";
          }
    echo $userpost['username'];
    echo $pioneer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As andrewsi said, you should reset you `$pioneer` variable each time you enter the loop.

```
while($post=mysql_fetch_assoc($p)){ 
  // defaults to 'False'
  $pioneer = 'False';
}
```

Another Option would be to introduce an else branch:

```
else {
  $pioneer = 'False';
}
```

Also, you should **NOT** use the deprecated MySQL extension anymore! Switch to MySQLi (with prepared Statements) or PDO!

Answer (score 1):

You're not resetting the value of `$pioneer` after each loop. Reset it to an empty string if it's not supposed to be `"true"`.

```
while($post=mysql_fetch_assoc($p)){ 
    $userpost=$user->getUserData($post['userid']);
        if($userpost['specialmembership'] == 1){
            $pioneer = "true";
        }else{
            $pioneer = "";
    echo $userpost['username'];
    echo $pioneer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

write

```
$p=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE forum_id='$cid' AND topic_id='$id'      

AND post_deleted='0' ORDER BY post_time ASC LIMIT  $offset, $rowsperpage");

while($post=mysql_fetch_assoc($p)){ 
$userpost=$user->getUserData($post['userid']);
      $pioneer="False";
      if($userpost['specialmembership'] == 1){
        $pioneer = "True";
      }
echo $userpost['username'];
echo $pioneer;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never reset your `$Pioneer` Variable

try

```
$pioneer = $userpost['specialmembership'] == 1 ? "True" : "False or Whatever you want";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding else condition like

```
while($post=mysql_fetch_assoc($p)){ 
    $userpost=$user->getUserData($post['userid']);
          $pioneer = ($userpost['specialmembership'] == 1? "True": "False");
echo $userpost['username'];
echo $pioneer;
}
```

or define $pioneer = "False" in the beginning and use your code

```
while($post=mysql_fetch_assoc($p)){ 
$userpost=$user->getUserData($post['userid']);

      if($userpost['specialmembership'] == 1){
        $pioneer = "True";
      }
echo $userpost['username'];
echo $pioneer;

}
```